# how to add a class to the input component in a wrapper in simple_form 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to have `class="text"` in my input fields when using a custom wrapper called :hinted in simple_form 2.0.0.rc

```
config.wrappers :hinted do |b|
  b.use :input, :class => "text"
end
```

but the output  doesn't have that class, I tried

```
:wrap_with => {:class => 'text'}
```

to no avail

Does anyone know how this is done?

Thank You!

Comment: so do you want to have class "text" on your inputs or on the wrapper?

Comment: input, I want <input class='text'> and I don't want this done inline as in <%= f.input :due_at, input_html: {class: 'text'} %>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently there no way to do this. You can use the `defaults` options like this if you want.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "text" } }) do %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that'll do it, actually, as those text fields that I need to have class "text" for is in a simple_fields_for for an association. Thanks Rafael

Comment: @rafaelfranca maybe we should implement it? I can help if it sounds like a good idea

Comment: @nash sure. If you want, you can try to make this a valid wrapper configuration

Comment: This will add that class to all the input elements. Check boxes, everythang.

Answer (score 46):

With :input_html works. It is a bit clunky.

```
= f.input :email, :input_html => { :class => 'foo' }
```

You can also set all the inputs on all the form elements:

```
simple_form_for(@user, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "foo" } })
```

But as you'd expect, this applies to everything.

You can create custom form elements:

```
# app/inputs/foo_input.rb
class FooInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input_html_classes
    super.push('foo')
  end
end

// in your view:
= f.input :email, :as => :foo
```

See: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-input-components

You can also create a custom form builder:

```
def custom_form_for(object, *args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!
  simple_form_for(object, *(args << options.merge(builder: CustomFormBuilder)), &block)
end

class CustomFormBuilder < SimpleForm::FormBuilder
  def input(attribute_name, options = {}, &block)
    options[:input_html].merge! class: 'foo'
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: In CustomFormBuilder, you should have options[:input_html] ||= {} before merging into it.

Answer (score 12):

This feature is about to be merged to master right now (Oct. 2012):

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/622

Then you can do something like this to add HTML attributes directly on the input field:

```
SimpleForm.build :tag => :div, :class => "custom_wrapper" do |b|
  b.wrapper :tag => :div, :class => 'elem' do |component|
    component.use :input, :class => ['input_class_yo', 'other_class_yo']
    component.use :label, :"data-yo" => 'yo'
    component.use :label_input, :class => 'both_yo'
    component.use :custom_component, :class => 'custom_yo'
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice.  Does that help me here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039336/grouping-checkboxes-for-individual-boolean-values-using-css-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: A year later. No merge!

Comment: @rafaelfranca Yep, I was looking for this too, today.

Comment: Gosh, this is gold, it needs to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, however it seems that this feature (the [input_class](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/622) one) was merged after the 3.0.0 version.

So I tried to make a monkey patch for supporting at least the `config.input_class = 'foo'` code

My intention is not to do a great monkey patch (in fact I like this article [here](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/) for doing that - the monkey patch), well it is only an idea but it works, now I'm working with the SimpleForm v2.1.3 and Bootstrap 4 - alpha version (the last one is not important here but it is just for an information purpose)

here is the code for the monkey patch:

```
module SimpleForm
  mattr_accessor :input_class
  @@input_class = nil
end
module SimpleForm
  module Inputs
    class Base
      def html_options_for(namespace, css_classes)
        html_options = options[:"#{namespace}_html"]
        html_options = html_options ? html_options.dup : {}
        css_classes << html_options[:class] if html_options.key?(:class)
        css_classes << SimpleForm.input_class if namespace == :input && SimpleForm.input_class.present?
        html_options[:class] = css_classes unless css_classes.empty?
        html_options
      end
    end
  end
end
```

now you can do something like this:

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # ...
  config.input_class = 'foo'
  #...
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You can setup this in simple_form initializer:

config.input_class = 'foo'

It works for me :)