# How to add a class to an erb statement (in a form, not a do statement)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am wondering how you can add a CSS class parameter to an ERB statement inside of a `do` statement like so;

```
<% @relatives&.each do |f| %>
  <%== f.summary %> <!-- This one here -->
<% end %>
```

I tried this: `<%== f.summary, class: "class-name" %>`

since it works in a form like this: `<%= f.input :name, class: "class-name" %>`

Is this even possible outside of a form?

The point of this is I am using CKEditor to write a summary for something and it is injecting it's own `<p>` tags, rendering the styles on `<p>` tags surrounding it useless.

It used to be written like this: `<p class="card-text basic"><%= raw f.summary %></p>`

Comment: What's going on with the `<%==`? That doesn't seem like correct syntax. The rest looks fine.

Comment: @Matthew It's crazy, I just learned what it does. `<%==` replaces `<%= raw`. "The double equal means that the string is not escaped" - Richard_G from the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996827/7372897).

Comment: Could you try without the `==` and see if you see the same behavior? You are comparing a working example `<%= f.input :name, class: 'class_name' %>` with something that might be causing some unknown side-effect.

Comment: @Matthew I've tried that, the same thing happens though.

Comment: Can you try with `input_html` as described here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371490/how-to-add-a-class-to-the-input-component-in-a-wrapper-in-simple-form-2

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, it doesn't worth with/without the raw tags. I even tried it without rocket-script.

Comment: The question is: what's in the `f` variable? `<%= f.input :name, class: "class-name" %>` means "send `input` (call method `input`) to `f`, passing symbol `:name` and hash `{:class => 'class-name'}`" as arguments. The output depends on what the method `f.input` returns.

Comment: If `f` is something like a string or an `ActiveRecord` or some other object not understanding `input`, it will just raise an error.

Comment: @igneus It's a string inside `p` tags (`<p>This text is the summary</p>`).

Comment: Than it, of course, won't work. If you need to modify HTML code you have in a string, the only really safe way is to parse it (with something like `Nokogiri::HTML`), modify the DOM tree and serialize it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

classes are attributes of DOM elments. Strings don't have classes.

You could wrap it in a span and assign the class to the span... do something like this...

```
<%= tag.span f.summary, class: 'class-name' %>
```

or to use p tag...

```
<%= tag.p f.summary, class: 'class-name' %>
```

Comment: While this does work to apply a class, it prevents me from using un-escaped code. I've tried using `<%==` and `<%= raw` but didn't work. Would you know how to pull this off? Also, what if there are multiple `<p>` tags in the string? Would this apply the class to each one?

Comment: Ah, right... I'm not at my desk right now, could you try `<%= tag.p f.summary.html_safe, class: 'class-name' %>` and see how that works?  Alternatively, `<%= (tag.p(f.summary.html_safe, class: 'class-name')).html_safe %>

Comment: Okay, the two examples you just gave are not applying the class but is displaying the text as raw and isn't displaying the `<p>` tags. _But_, `.html_safe` does work with `tag.span` and achieves everything! Why do you think it behaves like that?